# Finding features in map server

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm just starting with QGIS 3.

I have imported a WMS into my project. One of the attributes in these features is a PID (property id)

https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/WHSE_CADASTRE.PMBC_PARCEL_FABRIC_POLY_SVW/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

This is how these layers look like
[image]

Now, I need to be able to search for any of these IDs in this layer. There must be a way of doing this, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

A WMS service returns a picture of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data

Comment: Well I don't know then. When I click any of these tiles or the labels with that information viwer I see the attributes I'm interested in, including the PID. Doesn't that mean this is not only images ?

Comment: that is a `getFeatureInfo` and is designed to return information about a point you click on. You could theoretically click on each point of the map and save the results but a WFS is easier